# Javascript transformation

Tags: regex

Is there any simple way to transform:

```
"<A[hello|home]>"
```

to:

```
"hello|home"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, by removing the `<A[` and the `]>` parts :) Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If sp00m's suggestion isn't good enough you need to be more specific. Why can't you just delete the characters?

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought it was a more optimal solution to make a regular expression :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the clever advice in the comments to simply remove certain characters, if you are unable to remove these characters because they are present elsewhere in the text and do want to match that format, here is a way to do it with regex:

Search: `<\w+\[([^|]*\|[^\]]*)\]>`

Replace: `\1` or `$1` depending on editor or regex engine.

See the `Substitution` pane at the bottom of the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mZ4fK2).

**Explanation**

```
<\w+\[([^|]*\|[^\]]*)\]>
```

- Match the character “<” literally `<`
- Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation) `\w+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Match the character “[” literally `\[`
- Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `([^|]*\|[^\]]*)`

  - Match any character that is NOT a “|” `[^|]*`

    - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
  - Match the character “|” literally `\|`
  - Match any character that is NOT a “]” `[^\]]*`

    - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Match the character “]” literally `\]`
- Match the character “>” literally `>`

\1

- Insert the backslash character `\`
- Insert the character “1” literally `1`

Comment: @Jany Hey btw, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an answer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial. :)